# Change btn-group .active style in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using a Bootstrap .btn-group and toggling the button pressed to the active state like a radio button. I'm finding that there is not enough contrast on the button to tell that is was selected when setting it to .active state. I poked around the Less files and it looks like the .active removes the gradient background and adds a box shadow. Can anyone tell me an easy(not too invasive) way to darken the .active state of a .btn in .btn-group in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`.btn.active {background-color}` is defined at buttons.less line 50, but the "not too invasive" way for customizing this is to add add the following rule to your CSS and don't touch original Less.

```
.btn.active, .btn:active {
    background-color: #XXXXXX;
}
```

Comment: May want to do these changes in less since any updates in css could be overwritten. See http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html#compiling for multiple methods to compile less into css.